# Can't access directory of another user after giving equivalent access to both

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, sudo

I've edited the **/etc/sudoers** file through **visudo** and added

```
www-data        ALL=(git)       NOPASSWD: ALL
git             ALL=(www-data)  NOPASSWD: ALL
```

so now the user "git" should be able to execute commands as "www-data", but when I try to

```
sudo -u git ls /tmp/redmine_git_hosting
```

I get:

```
ls: cannot open directory /tmp/redmine_git_hosting/: Permission denied
```

The permissions of directory are:

```
drwx------  2 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 31 09:02 redmine_git_hosting
```

I can list directory by running:

```
sudo -u www-data ls /tmp/redmine_git_hosting
```

Comment: As you can see. Owner has `rwx`  permissions while group has no permissions at all. You need to add git in the www-data group and change directory permissions of `redmine_git_hosting` to `drwx-rw---` so git could read and write.

Comment: @val0x00ff: That doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've misunserstood how sudo works. What it does is let the user git use sudo to run commands as the user www-data - but in order to do that, the user git has to run sudo, it's not enough that you become the user without using sudo **from that user**.

In short, you'd need to do something like

```
 sudo -u git sudo -u www-data ls /tmp/redmine_git_hosting
```

instead.